# Add sql query results to email template

Tags: php, mysql, email

The code below works correctly when sending the email-template.php file. I would now like to include the results of the SQL query in the email template in a table, basically it's a list of quotes. I have a feeling `str_replace` is the way to go but being a complete newbie, I'm not sure how to do this.

```
<?php
      include('connect.php');
      include('functions.php');


    $sql = "SELECT Quote FROM daily_quote Order By rand() Limit 0,10";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);



    $to = 'example@example.com';
    $subject = "Test";

    $htmlContent = file_get_contents("email-template.php");

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'From: info@example.com' . "\r\n";


    // Send email
    if(mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers)):
        $successMsg = 'Email has sent successfully.';
    else:
        $errorMsg = 'Email sending fail.';
    endif;
    include('footer.php');
```

Comment: You should avoid getting into the habit of declaring a throw-away SQL string and instead put the query directly inside the `query(...)` call. This avoids mistakes where you accidentally run the wrong query. Likewise, the `if (...):` style is the [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and isn't really encouraged.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with `str_replace()` for that simple task. Define a placeholder in the template and replace it with the generated string containing the HTML table. For more complex templates (or if you just want to separate data processing and presentation) you might consider to use a template engine like smarty, twig or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in email-template.php add:
 {place_holder}

edit your script in this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT Quote FROM daily_quote Order By rand() Limit 0,10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$template = "<table>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $template .= "<tr><td>".$row['Quote']."</td></tr>";
$template .=  "</table>";
```

and edit

```
if(mail($to,$subject,str_replace("{place_holder}",$template,$htmlContent),$headers)):
```

Comment: The PHP is displayed as test in the email rather than the resulting HTML. How do I get the results to correctly display?

Comment: excuse my English, can you give me an example?

Comment: Thanks, this is the output copied from the actual email: echo "
"; while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo "
".$row['Quote']."
"; echo "
";

Comment: Works perfectly ad makes sense. Thank you.